# Term for converting to black&white

Tags: terminology, latin, greek, colors

Is there a single word to denote reducing the color palette of an image to two colors: black and white? For instance, navy becomes black and beige turns into white.

I know there is *desaturate*, but it's too broad, can mean even a slight reduction in color.

Comment: I was hoping that "to gray scale" would be a verb, but I couldn't find it used as such in any dictionary. You still could use it, I suppose. I rather like the idea of "grayscaling" something. Also black-and-white images mostly have more shades than black and white. EDIT: On second thought, you should ignore this and go with Andrew Leach's answer.

Comment: @KaiserOctavius, I'd be happy with "to gray scale" as a form, however, technically gray scale isn't two colors. I realize that the difference is extralinguistic, but the term I'm looking for must ultimately refer to only black and white.

Comment: Are you asking about using black and white only, or allowing for various shades of grey as well?

Comment: @blb Only black as is my heart, and white as is my sorrow.

Comment: @KaiserOctavius, I'm suprised no-one has started saying _grey-scale_. I look forward to _monochrome_ or _monotint_ appearing as verbs too.

Comment: @BrianHooper, `monochrome`, exactly! I'd accept the noun as well.

Comment: Except that both *monochrome* and *monotint* mean "grey-scale", and also include a similar "red-scale" or "blue-scale" -- graduated tints of a single colour. And they are all already commonly used as verbs.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, hmm, time to scratch head.

Comment: Not sure why. What you describe (going to **only** black and white) is either *two-colour posterization* [for most uses these days] or *one-colour posterization* [for letterpress printing with real ink].

Comment: In GIMP the tool for this, and therefore the associated jargon or technical term used by GIMP users, is "Threshold".

Comment: There is *decolor* or *decolorize*, and while those mean *remove color*, they are usually equated to *bleaching* and contemplate lightening dark colors, not shifting them to black.

Comment: I think I shall vote to get it moved. Specialist terms for which there is already a relevant SE site should really go to that site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it requires a specialist term for which the [Graphic Design Stack](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) would be more suited.

Comment: @bib, thanks for ruling "decolor" out!

Comment: You just want to say that something that is ***“completely desaturated”***, as opposed to being “somewhat undersaturated”. You don’t need a special word for this.

Comment: Good question, but you should better have it asked on an appropriate site or SO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The proper term for converting an image to black and white is **binarize**. The process of doing so is called **binarization**.

From [Wiktionary:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/binarize)

> **binarize** (*third-person singular simple present binarizes, present participle binarizing, simple past and past participle binarized*)
>
> 1. (mathematics) To represent in binary
> 2. **To convert (an image) to only black and white.**

An example usage would be: *"The first step is to **binarize** the image by applying a threshold."*

Comment: Yay! Thanks so much for the precise term and the threshold  example!

Comment: All photographs are already represented in binary.

Comment: @tchrist That "binary" has nothing to do with what we are talking about here.

Answer (score 5):

This question might be better asked at [GD.SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) but there is ***posterize***:

> **posterize** *verb*
>   [*with object*]
>   print or display (a photograph or other image) using only a small number of different tones:
>      *posterize the image and view the result*
>
> [[ODO]](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/posterize)

The term is derived from letterpress printing of posters, where only a limited number of solid colours were easily used.

Original and posterized images (using Paint Shop Pro's *posterize* function):

[image: Queen Elizabeth II Conference Centre, London]
[image: Posterized image]

Comment: The inner form and semantics of "posterize" seems even further than "desaturate". The images you provided, though, illustrate gray scale and b&w beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: @katspaugh Added explanation: "The term is derived from letterpress printing of posters, where only a limited number of solid colours were easily used." You could have more than just one colour (black) on white.

Comment: But you can also posterize a color picture, and that results in an image still in color, but with a non-continuous tonal range with only a few (usually primary) colors.

Comment: @bib Exactly. A limited number of solid colours. This answer describes either *two-colour posterization* [for most uses these days] or *one-colour posterization* [for letterpress printing with real ink].

Comment: @AndrewLeach But the OP specifically is asking for only black and white as the result [see comments], and the example he offers is already posterized - a two color blue/beige being converted to a two color black/white.

Comment: @bib That's a simple recolour; blue and beige could simply be indicating which side of a threshold those values fall.

Comment: Andrew, so a "solid color" is a color which doesn't have tones or a color which have only one tone?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Yes (think about it).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with most of the suggestions above and will offer a few more:

- Adopt the terminology "convert [*source*] to *destination*," as insisting on making everything a verb just makes most of the verbs very clumsy
- *threshold* could be a synonym for posterizing to monochrome
- *halftone to 1-bit monochrome* would cover another example of output in only one colorant (trading off spatial resolution for pixel depth)

  - but then you may want to state what kind of halftone (clustered dot screens with frequency and angle, or stochastic screens, or hybrids)

Comment: Thanks, Liudvikas! How would you use `threshold` in a sentence like "Let's convert this image to *x*" or "This color *x*-ed would be black"?

Comment: "Let's threshold the grayscale image at the median value" would be shorthand for "Let's select a threshold value T such that half the pixels are lighter than T, half are darker than T, and output an image where pixels are black when input pixels are lighter than the threshold T."  That would be comprehensible to someone who knows what Andrew Leach's posterized example is actually doing.  In general, "to threshold" is image processing shorthand for "do one thing for input that exceeds some value, another thing for input that doesn't".